# How to hide computer name and user name in terminal command prompt

Tags: macos, terminal

How can I hide username and computer in terminal command prompt?

In Terminal it says

```
Last login: Mon Jan 13 00:00:14 on ttys000
Whatever:~ UserName$
```

Is it possible to show just the current folder and `$` sign?

Comment: What do you mean by *show current folder*? The current folder is already shown after the ``:``. BTW: I've changed the computer name in **System Preferences -> Sharing** to MBP. Now my login prompt is very short: ``mbp:~ matt$``

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Change your prompt in your ~/.bashrc file. The example you asked for would be:

```
export PS1="\W \$"
```

It would result in the current folder you're in being shown plus a $ for the regular prompt and a # if you're root. Check out [this guide](https://web.archive.org/web/20180607003133/https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-tip-prompt/) for more examples of what you could show in your prompt.

**Edit:**

As per one of the comments below, you might need to source your `~/.bashrc` from your `~/.bash_profile` or even put this code in your `~/.bash_profile` instead. You can read [this article](https://www.golinuxcloud.com/bashrc-vs-bash-profile/) for a better explanation on which file to use.

**If you are NOT using BASH but ***ZSH***, do the following:**

(1) `nano ~/.zshrc`,
(2) add this line at the end of the file `export PS1="\$ "`,
(3) save the file, ~/.zshrc,
(4) source the zshrc to apply the change with `source ~/.zshrc`.
(5) You should be good at this point!

Comment: If you are not using `bash` but `zsh`, do the following:

(1) `nano ~/.zshrc`, (2) add this line at the end of the file `export PS1="\$ "`, (3) save the file, `~/.zshrc`, (4) source the `zshrc` to apply the change with `source ~/.zshrc`

Comment: To check which shell you are using, you can use the following command:

`echo $SHELL`

Answer (score 35):

I had a similar issue with this but did not get it working at first.

This may of been because I wasn't sudo but either way this works just as well.

1. Open the preferences in the terminal (top right)
2. Then go into the shell tab
3. Then copy/paste the command  `export PS1="\W \$"; clear;`
4. Then restart the terminal and should work

[image]

Comment: This is the best for temporary solutions.

Comment: What is the "\W" supposed to do? For me it just leaves a literal "\W"  before the dollar sign

Comment: @Tom the `\W` is supposed to be working directory path. I think it should actually be lowercase though. However, if you are using the default Mac terminal, you aren't using bash, you are using zsh. try this:
`export PS1="%~ $ "`

Answer (score 22):

```
echo "export PS1='$ '" >> ~/.bash_profile
. ~/.bash_profile
```

This will leave just `$` as a prompt. If you want to restore the old prompt, you will need to edit .bash_profile to remove that "export ..." line.

Comment: This worked like a charm in bash shell in CentOS 7

Answer (score 13):

Check out [this tutorial](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html) on how to change your bash prompt.
A very short version (only username and no current path):
`PS1="\u$ "`

Result: `myusername$ cat something.log`

Comment: It works, now the problem is it will not save the new bash prompt. It will show the old one after i shut down my mac. Why?

Comment: Did you put the variable in the following file: `/Users/<yourusername>/.bash_profile`?

Answer (score 5):

Edit ~/.bash_profile to save your changes to prompt.

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

At the end, add your changes.

```
# Change prompt
export PS1="\W \$ "
```

Exit, save changes. Hit enter to confirm the file name.
Run source to see the change.

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked nicely for me, using OSX 10.12 Sierra.

Comment: Why use `sudo`?

Comment: Thanks for putting the space after the dollar sign!

Answer (score 3):

Create/Edit your .bash_profile file or your root:

```
sudo vim ~/.bash_profile
```

and add this line

```
export PS1="\W$: "
```

The space will give you some breathing space in command prompt.
After this modification your command prompt will looks like this:

```
~$:
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `DEFAULT_USER` in `~/.zshrc` file to your regular username. You can get your exact username value by executing `whoami` in the terminal.
Something like this:

```
export DEFAULT_USER=username
```

Answer (score 0):

export PS1="[\033[01;32m]\W \$ [\033[00m]"

\W will give you the current folder (\w to include the path too). The brackets set the color codes. So this puts the current folder in green, and then resets the color to white after the prompt.

Answer (score -3):

Mine is: PS1="\W[\033[32m]\$(parse_git_branch)[\033[00m] $ "

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.

Comment: Delete, i don't care i was only trying to help!