# Is it possible to replace my username in Terminal with special characters?

Tags: terminal, macos

I found [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/34910/how-to-hide-computer-name-and-user-name-in-terminal-command-prompt) which seems close to the solution, but it's not quite there.

EDIT: With JavaScript, I know I can just run `test.replace(/\w/g, "*")`, where `test` is my username, but I don't know the equivalent for the Terminal.

Comment: **What special characters?** Have you read `PROMPT_COMMAND` and `PROMPTING` in the `BASH` manual page? In Terminal type `bash` then right-click on it and select `Open man Page`. Then ⌘F and search for and read about it. Have you [googled - how to customize the bash command prompt](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=how+to+customize+the+bash+command+prompt)? This one is good: [How to: Change / Setup bash custom prompt (PS1)](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html)

Comment: @user3439894 I've looked at those but I still don't understand how to change my username to `*****` (those are the special characters I was talking about). I understand that I'd use `PRMOPT_COMMAND` to do this before `$PS1` starts.

Comment: You really should clarify the question to explain that you want to replace the username *in the command prompt*, not in other contexts that it appears in Terminal.

Comment: @GordonDavisson I did and my question got answered.

Comment: @NetOperatorWibby You got the answer you wanted, but part of the point of this site is to let other people with the same (or similar) question find yours & its answers. Therefore, it's best to make your questions as clear, unambiguous, and search-term-friendly as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hidden username should be the same length as the original username? Like so:

Alices-MacBook:~ *****

Bobs-MacBook:~ ***

The following code snippet should do the job (and, as a bonus, it'll also hide hostname). Add it to your ~/.bash_profile, or wherever you set PS1. (I created a temporary file - test.sh - for testing, and then sourced that file - '. ./test.sh'. If something had gone spectacularly wrong, and I'd made my prompt illegible, I could simply restart the terminal and be back to my old prompt).

```
PROMPT_COMMAND=__prompt_command

__hide_string()
{
    echo "$1" | sed 's/./\*/g'
}

__prompt_command()
{
    PS1="$(__hide_string $HOSTNAME):\W $(__hide_string $USER)\$"
}
```

This will replace every character in the username with a "*" (it'll also do it for the hostname, to show function reuse). I consider this to be less than ideal - the function gets called (twice - once for user, once for hostname) every time the prompt is displayed (even though the username hasn't changed): with a bit of hacking it should be possible to amend it so that it only calls the '__hide_string' function when PS1 is set (i.e. at login).

Explanation: the __prompt_command function we've defined sets PS1 every time the prompt is displayed. (This is probably overkill, but keeps things 'dynamic'). PS1 should be familiar; the only new stuff is that '\h' and '\u' are replaced with calls to the __hide_string function (and use $HOSTNAME and $USER as arguments). __hide_string is the fun part: it echoes its argument to sed, which replaces every individual character with a '*'.

Comment: Thank you! I use zsh-shell so I had to customize a bit for my theme but the end result is still the same. :D

Answer (score 1):

The `PS1` prompt is defined in `/etc/bashrc` and the default is usually `PS1='\h:\W \u\$ '`. You'd replace the `\u` with `*****`. You could also just add, e.g `export PS1='\h:\W *****\$ '` to your `~/.bash_profile` file, while leaving the system file (`/etc/bashrc`) alone.

Comment: Hmm, so there's no way to do this dynamically? I'd want the amount of asterisks to match the amount of characters in my username, without setting the length manually.

Comment: You could get a string of asterisks the same length as the username with `${USER//?/*}` (i.e. export PS1="\h:\W ${USER//?/*}\$ "). Note that since the username won't change during a session, this only needs to be run once per session (in ~/.bash_profile and possibly also ~/.bashrc) rather than once per prompt (with PROMPT_COMMAND).